Typst: Cannot reference heading/equations/figure/whatever without numbering
How to use reference without numberings. I really do not want to set the numbering, since it is very customized or I just do not want to use numbers! This should still be possible.
= Header
<my-header>

Please see @my-header[the Header]

I know I could just use
#set heading(numbering: "1.")

This however add automatic numeration to my headers, which is not what I want. I want to reference it, not to enumerate it.
This should be however possible, or there should be workarounds! besides cluttering the document with custom notation every single reference?

The error is given because @ref style uses a supplemental label, like Section 1 which isn't possible without a numbering format. An alternative is to just use the link function:
#show link: it => {
  set text(blue)
  underline(it)
}

= Header
<my-header>
Please see #link(<my-header>)[My Header]

Of course, you can always write your own show rule for refs to enable @ syntax:
#let blue-underline(it) = underline[
  #set text(blue)
  #it
]

#show link: blue-underline


#show ref: it => {
  if it.element.numbering == none {
    // Use your custom scheme
    link(it.target, it.element.body)
  } else {
    // Default `ref`
    it
  }
}

= The Header
<my-header>

= Another header
<another-header>

Please see #link(<my-header>)[This heading] for more details.

Or, check out @another-header



first solution worked, second did not work, but thank you very much

What was your error using the second appraoch?

in the web app at least the links or clicking did not work

I've updated the answer to include hyperlinking for @ references. Basically, it's just wrapping in link instead of blue-underline
